# Easy deletion of some commits from history

Tags: git, github

I tried to find a way to remove unnecessary commits from both local and GitHub repositories. I've just found complicated answers which I don't understand very well, since I am a Spanish speaker and I don't know much about Git. Some talk about `rebase master` or `cherry-pick`. I tried reading up on those concepts but it's kind of hard to understand.

I thought that it could be easily done with a GUI, in a list checking checkboxes and then pressing a button which says "delete commits". Does that kind of thing exist?

I'd like to delete all my commits with the default message "new commit" and some others, so I keep only the important commits.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I want to keep the changes made by the deleted commits, so my last commit doesn't change.

[image: github repo commits]

Comment: Use `git rebase -i `

Comment: Exactly, in the `rebase -i` dialog, remove those commits you don't want.

Comment: Do you really want to delete the commits (i.e. remove all changes introduced by them) or do you want to keep the changes introduced by them but don't want them to show up in history? If you want to delete them, use `git rebase -i` and drop all lines with the commits you don't want. Things will get messy because sooner or later you'll end up in conflicts. If you want to keep the changes but drop the commit messages, do a `git rebase -i` again but instead of deleting lines, select `squash` as action.

Comment: Not to forget: the standard disclaimer of modifying published history: **do not change the history of published repositories**. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Comment: Yes, of course I want to keep the changes, just don't showed up in history

Comment: When doing `git rebase -i` it says : `There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.`

Comment: So I did `git rebase -i Master` and the interactive mode appeared, but I don't know what to do then, i typed `squash`  on the first line, it highlighted with red, now how to applied it? also I don't see any commit list